# No notifications from Telegram on BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I can't see notifications from the Telegram app on the new BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition

Answer (score 2):

Telegram was unable to connect to our servers for a few hours today because we stopped allowing SSLv3 connections. They've fixed it now.

Comment: I reported a bug in Launchpad since notifications are broken again after the last OTA update (r21)

Answer (score 1):

Notification system is still very buggy. I managed to get telegram notifications working using the Ubuntu One account, but after last Telegram update (v1.1.2(95)) for Bq phones it stopped working again and couldn't get it to work.
Make sure you don't have any other telegram instance open in your computer or other phones or you will not get notifications.

Comment: I don't think they're buggy; if you have instances of them not working, please report every one of them.

Comment: Reported in Launchpad again. Notifications are broken after the last OTA.

Comment: Could you link to the bug, please?